# Appending strings results in "realloc(): Invalid pointer"

Tags: c, memory-management

I have a function *append_string*, which appends str2 to str1:

```c
void append_string(char* str1, char* str2) {
    int    new_length = strlen(str1)+strlen(str2);
    size_t new_size = sizeof(char)*(new_length);
    str1 = (char*) realloc(str1, new_size);
    strcat(str1, str2);
}
```

As shown in the function, I'm trying to increase the size using a the combined size of the strings.

Whenever I call `append_str("", "adc");`, I get `"realloc(): Invalid pointer"`

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least these problems:

**Attempting to reallocate something not allocated.**

`realloc(str1, new_size)` attempts to reallocate the *string literal* `""` leading to "realloc(): Invalid pointer".

**Size off by 1**

New size did not account for the *null character*.

```
// size_t new_size = sizeof(char)*(new_length);
size_t new_size = sizeof(char)*(new_length + 1);
```

**Code loses the allocated pointer**

Calling code lost the value of the new pointer `str`.

**Weak type for sizing**

Use `size_t`.

---

Instead, pass in an allocated pointer or `NULL` by its address.

```
void append_string(char** str, const char* appendage) {
  size_t new_length = strlen(*str) + strlen(appendage);
  size_t new_size = sizeof(char)*(new_length + 1);
  *str = realloc(*str, new_size);
  strcat(*str, appendage);
}

// Usage
char *s = malloc(1);
strcpy(s, "");
append_str(&s, "adc");
puts(s);
```

---

Advanced issues include:

- What to do if `realloc()` returns `NULL`?
- How to handle `appendage` overlapping `str`?
- Do not use `strcat()`. Avoid [slow code](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/schlemiel_the_painter%27s_algorithm).  Better to retain the original string length and copy from there.

  ```
    void append_string(char** str, const char* appendage) {
      size_t str_len = *str ? strlen(*str) : 0;
      size_t app_len = strlen(appendage);
      void *p = realloc(*str, str_len + app_len + 1);
      if (p == NULL) {    
        // Handle Error - various approaches
        free(*str);
        *str = NULL;
      } else {        
        strcpy(*str + str_len, appendage);
      }
    }
  ```

Still need to handle case when `appendage` overlaps `*str`.

```
    void append_string_when_overlap_possible(char** str, const char* appendage) {
      size_t str_len = *str ? strlen(*str) : 0;
      size_t app_len = strlen(appendage);
      char *p = malloc(str_len + app_len + 1);
      if (p == NULL) {    
        // Handle Error - various approaches
        free(*str);
        *str = NULL;
      } else {        
        if (*str) {
          strcpy(p, *str);
        }
        strcpy(p + str_len, appendage);
        free(*str);
        *str = p;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Wow! This is so descriptive and easy to understand! Thank you! Although, I don't understand what you meant in the section "Code loses the allocated pointer". Could you please elaborate a bit more on that?

Comment: @TahminAhmed After `str1 = (char*) realloc(str1, new_size);`, `str` is used in the next line `strcat(str1, str2);` and then that is it.  The allocated data's pointer is then lost after the function ends - memory still allocated, but no place in user code saved the pointer value.